# How to reload tableview data one array to another array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am trying to create single `table view` with dual `NSMutableArray` values. now I have maintaining `UISegmentcontrol` first button click to load first `NSMutableArray` data. Second button click to load second `NSMutableArray` data values(after clicking second button first data should not display).

```
NSMUtableArray *firstarray = [First values];
NSMUtableArray *secondarray = [second values];


-(void)segmentedControlValueDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
    switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:{
            //action for the first button (Current)
           //want to load first array data into table
            break;}
        case 1:{
            //action for the first button (Current)
           //want to load second array data into table
           break;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create 1 array to hold the data for table, so you don't have to check (using if, ...) in every delegate methods of UITableView:

```
NSMutableArray * arrTableData;

-(void)segmentedControlValueDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
    switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:{
            arrTableData = firstarray;
           [tableView reloadData];

            break;}
        case 1:{
             arrTableData = secondarray;
             [tableView reloadData];

           break;}
    }
}
```

Using `arrTableData` for delegates of `UITableView`: `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellAtIndex`...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

   return arrTableData.count;

}
```

Comment: But for first time what I do? before selecting buttons I need to list defaulty firstarray data@anthu

Comment: Yes, you will choose which is the default by assign `arrTableData` = `firstarray` somewhere.

Comment: When you set the selected segment you can also set the initial value of the array

Comment: Hi. where can i assign this for default arrTableData = firstarray @anthu

Comment: `viewDidLoad` , or somewhere you got `firstarray` the first time, or before you load table the first time.

Comment: Thank you buddy @anthu.. I did!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an enum to check which button you pressed. For button one set enum value to 1, and for button two set enum value to 2. In in table view delegate methods you can check currently selected enum and return the appropriate value.

For example :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSInteger count = 0;


if(m_choice == 1)
    count = [firstarray count];
else if(m_choice == 2)
    count = [secondarray count];

return count;}
```

And do this to other table view methods too.

Comment: While this will work it's a lot of duplicate code and the other answer is a more elegant approach

Answer (score 1):

Implement your `UITableViewDelegate` in this following way

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   if (mySegmentContorll.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
       // Draw Cell content with data taken from first array, data = firstarray[indexPath]
   } else if (mySegmentContorll.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
      // Draw Cell content with data taken from second array, data = secondarray[indexPath]
   }

}
```

Also call `[tableView reloadData];` when segmented control changes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a bool variable say isLoadFirst
then in your Following Code

```
-(void)segmentedControlValueDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:{
         isFirstLoad  = YES;
         [yourTableView reloadData];
        //action for the first button (Current)
       //want to load first array data into table
        break;}
    case 1:{
        //action for the first button (Current)
       //want to load second array data into table
        isFirstLoad  = NO;
         [yourTableView reloadData];
       break;}
}
}
```

Now in your

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     if (isFirstLoad)
   return firstArrayCount;
   else 
   return secondArrayCount
}
```

And same check for

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thank you Arsian. Its also nice answer!